How to avoid imports that are not used?
I have class A which imports class B just to have an enum defined in class B.
However, class B has heaps of imports that are useless to class A, and that increases the JavaScript size when the user is in class A screen.
Is there a way to avoid these imports to be packed by webpack in this given screen without having to completely re-write the application?

I’m pretty sure you’re at the mercy of whatever packages they bundled with their library as dependencies.

You don't exactly "avoid" unused imports, you eliminate them from your code. In general, you would do this manually by going through your code and removing any import statements which import modules or code libraries that your code doesn't actually use.
However, there are tools like ESLint with the "no-unused-var" rule that can help with identifying unused variables, which essentially will help you identify the unused imports.
